# github forks filter search not working

Tags: github

I'm trying to find all of my repos with more than no forks so that I can start cleaning them up. But the filter doesn't seem to be working. I think I'm following [the documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-for-repositories/#search-by-number-of-forks) verbatim with `forks:0` but it is still showing repositories with forks.

Am I missing something? Is this feature broken? Does it only work above `0`?

[image]

I noticed some of them are ones I forked from others where my specific fork hasn't been forked by anyone else. I think that is actually the desired behavior.

The issue I'm having is that there are some that are private repositories with private forks that have been forked by others, but even in those cases it is still showing. The explanation could be that private forks do not count? Is that the case? If so, how can I search for repos with 0 forks public or private?

Comment: I just tested the query with my own account, and it does work with '0'.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I just checked and it seems like it might have something to do with private forks not counting toward the total? I added more details to the description.

Comment: Yes, private repos would not count as fork, making your repo visible by a `forks:0` search query.

Comment: But when I make the repo visible, it destroys the private forks. Is there any way to search for repositories with 0 public or private forks? https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/#changing-a-private-repository-to-a-public-repository

Comment: Not sure, considering a private fork remains... private.